# How to post to NSNotificationCenter regarding bool state?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to get the hang of using notifications. In my view controller class, I have a bool isFullScreen. When the value of this bool changes, I want to a notification to be sent to all observing classes. I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this, since a BOOL is not an object. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:YourNotificationName object:[NSNumber numberWithBool:isFullScreen]]; //YourNotificationName is a string constant
```

KVO Example:

If you were to do it with KVO, it would be something like the below.... :

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isFullScreen" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:nil];

- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
if ([keyPath isEqualToString: @"isFullScreen"]) {
        BOOL newValue = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] boolValue];
    }
}

//and in dealloc
[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isFullScreen" ];
```

Comment: So any time isFullScreen value changes, this notification gets sent?

Comment: What you might prefer is adding KVO on the isFullScreen variable. Read up on this. You register as a KVO observer for isFullScreen and any time it changes, you will be notified

Comment: I have to manually send a notification everytime I change the value? How would I do this?

Comment: Well if you are to use notifications, you could override - (void) setIsFullScreen:(BOOL)fullScreen { } and put your notification in there

Comment: The first line in his answer is what you have to type/copy-paste every time you change the value. Edit: or you can do what bandejapsaisa suggested as that's better =P

Comment: In the addObserver part, if the class that is to be observing is another class besides self, how would I indicate that?

Comment: self just reference the current object. So you can replace self with any object. [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isFullScreen"... means I (self) want to listen to changes on my (self) own property isFullScreen. If isFullScreen is a property on another object, you would write, [self addObserver:self.otherObject forKeyPath:@"isFullScreen".... (assuming otherObject is a properly on your current class).

Answer (score 5):

Just [wrap](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSNumber/numberWithBool%3a) BOOL in NSNumber:

```
[NSNumber numberWithBool:myBool]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap a BOOL in NSNumber like bandejapaisa and beryllium mentioned. However, for notifying observers of changes to a simple property, you're better off using Key Value Observing (KVO), instead of NSNotificationCenter. You get KVO "for free" as long as you've implemented or @synthesized KVC compliant accessor methods. Something like this:

```
// In your .h:

@interface YourViewController : UIViewController

@property (getter = isFullScreen) BOOL fullScreen;

@end

// In your .m:

@implementation YourViewController

@synthesize fullScreen;

@end

// In your observer class(es):

// Start observing the viewController for changes to fullScreen (in awakeFromNib, or wherever it makes sense)
[self.viewController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"fullScreen" options:0 context:NULL];

// This method is called when an observed value changes
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (object == viewController && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"fullScreen"]) 
    {
        if (self.viewController.isFullScreen)
        {
            // Do whatever you need to do in response to isFullScreen being true
        }
        else
        {
            // Do whatever you need to do in response to isFullScreen being false
        }
    } 
}
```

For this to work, you need to make sure you actually call the setter for the fullScreen property. So, always do `self.fullScreen = YES` of `[self setFullScreen:YES]` instead of `fullScreen = YES`. Otherwise, the setter method isn't called, and KVO isn't triggered.

You should read the [documentation on KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177i). Understanding it is pretty fundamental to being a good iOS programmer.

Comment: So I have two classes, FirstClass and SecondClass. FirstClass has property isFullScreen. How would this look if I want SecondClass to be aware of any changes to FirstClass.isFullScreen?

Comment: SecondClass would have to know about your instance(s) of FirstClass, either via an Interface Builder connection or through a relationship set up programmatically. SecondClass will register itself as an observer of changes to the FirstClass instance's fullScreen property, and will then be notified with the property changes.

Answer (score 1):

The `object` of a notification should be the object posting the notification, not an `NSNumber`. This is important so that the observer can observe specific instances, and so that it is obvious to the caller what the values all. Passing data in `object` is an easy way to get "does not respond to selector" crashes. Change data generally goes in the `userInfo` dict, but simple BOOLs are generally handled with two notifications. In this case you would have:

```
MYViewControlDidEnterFullScreenNotification
MYViewControlDidExitFullScreenNotification
```

The `object` should be the relevant view controller.

Note that these notifications are extremely clear in their timing. Both happen *after* the state has changed. You can also have equivalent `Will` notifications. Look at the [notification list](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for `NSWindow` for a good example of how to do this correctly. Note particularly `NSWindowDidEnterFullScreenNotification` and its relatives.

You may also be interested in [Some thoughts on NSNotifications](http://robnapier.net/blog/thoughts-nsnotifications-42).

The comments on KVO are good, and often KVO is a decent way to achieve this. But notifications are good, too, and easier to understand and debug than KVO.

Answer (score 1):

The object field of the notification is Intended to pass the sender and not additional parms

The correct way is to use the userInfo to send a key value dictionary

For example

```
- (void)postNotificationFullScreen //post notification method and logic
{
    NSString *notificationName = @"applicationFullScreen";
    NSString *key = @"fullScreen";
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:self.fullScreen] forKey:key];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:notificationName object:nil userInfo:dictionary];
}
```

And the to read this

```
NSString *notificationName = @"applicationFullScreen";

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(useFullScreen:) 
    name:notificationName 
    object:nil];

- (void)useFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification //use notification method and logic
{
    NSString *key = @"fullScreen";
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [notification userInfo];
    BOOL boolValue;
    if([dictionary valueForKey:key]) 
       boolValue =[[dictionary valueForKey:key] boolValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may get your head around this with using an NSMutableString* as @"YES" and @"NO".  Then when you set string to @"YES" and everything observing in KVO would be notified:

```
[myStringProperty setString:@"YES"];
```

You must use the NSString setString value.That is what actually calls it.

WARNING Do NOT use:

```
myStringProperty = @"YES";
```

(This will not produce KVO notifications.)